# i cant extend from dashbord.html.twig

Tags: symfony

Unable to inherit from dashbord.html.twig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXNvP.png)enter {% extends 'SocieteBundle::dashbord.html.twig' %}

Comment: Avoid using images in questions.  Just paste in the code in question and use the formater to make it display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% extends '@SocieteBundle/dashbord.html.twig' %}`

Comment: Please use the English language. If the answer above solves your problem, or helps solve your problem, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: if i add {id} in route the page does not display but without {id} page work   this is my rout pagemodif:
    path:     /pagemodif
    defaults: { _controller: SocieteBundle:Conge:pagemodif}

Comment: routing is a different problem.